# Why do I get an invalid syntax error with a foreach loop?

Tags: stata, stata-macros

I want to `rename` variable names starting with `intensity`. I received an invalid syntax, `r(198)` error, with the following code.

```
#delimit;

foreach VAR of varlist intensity* {;

 local NEW = subinstr("`VAR'", "intensity", "int");
 rename `VAR' `NEW';

 };
```

Comment: Not worth a separate answer on its own, but note that using the `trace` feature is (often) a helpful command for debugging. See `help trace`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your use of the delimiter `;` here does not bite, so I will ignore it.

The error is in the use of `subinstr()`, which must have four arguments, the fourth being the number of substitutions to be made. See `help subinstr()`.

This works (note please the use of a minimal complete verifiable example):

```
clear 
set obs 1 
generate intensity1 = 1 
generate intensity2 = 2 

foreach VAR of varlist intensity* {
    local NEW = subinstr("`VAR'", "intensity", "int", 1)
    rename `VAR' `NEW'
}

ds
```

But the loop is utterly unnecessary. First, let's flip the names back and then show how to change names directly:

```
rename int* intensity*
rename intensity* int*
```

See `help rename groups` for more.